# Burning smell after blower fan resistor replacement

Tags: vw, polo, heater-blower

Just replaced the Blow Fan resistor in my VW Polo. The fan works again but there's a burning smell coming from fan. Any experience of this team? The levels of air all work now but the smell is quite alarming. No smoke, just the smell. I haven't kept the fan on BTW. I switch off when smell comes.

Comment: Was it the correct resistor? Or the motor is failing and overheating.

Comment: Solar Mike, I'm pretty sure it was. I got it on Ebay and I had to answer about 5 drop down questions to get the correct one. There's 28 thousand miles on it and it's in good shape otherwise. What's your thoughts? Cheers btw.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: One possibility is that whatever caused the first blower resistor to burn up is now affecting the new one.  It's possible the blower motor is binding up or has some other issue that is causing it to draw excess current which is then causing the resistor to dissipate more heat than it's designed to.

Comment: The connector to the resistor could have gotten hot and damaged the wires or connector from the previous resistor. This can cause resistance creating unwanted heat.

Comment: Were you able to use the blower on the max setting? Typically the blower resistor only works for the intermediate fan speeds, there's no resistance for the max setting, which is why most blowers work on max even when the resistor has broken. If it worked on max did you get a burning smell with the old resistor?

Comment: GdG, thats exactly what happened. It worked fine on the max setting but no others. When on the max setting there was no burning smell also.

Comment: I replaced a resistor (medium speed) in one fan based on the original specs. Dual fans.  With ac use, fans start on low then ramp up to medium then high depending on ac pressures and cooling system temps. No low or medium speed in one fan. The replacement resistor lasted a short time before burning out. Replaced the fan. Infrequent electrical burning smell. My car was 17 yrs old so things wear out.

Comment: F Dryer, I'll have a look at the fan tomorrow. Could very well be that. Thank you.